# what is trigger movement of a batsman in cricket?

Tags: cricket, trivia

What is trigger movement of a batsman?When a bowler is going to bowl a ball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any movement a batsman makes just prior to the bowler releasing the ball is known to cricket coaches as a pre-delivery movement, or to players more commonly as trigger movements.

Throughout history many top class players have had trigger movements as part of their pre-delivery routine and some have been very indifferent. Many players utilise the *back and across* trigger movement whilst others take a small step forward with their front foot, others may merely crouch (as was the case with Brian Lara).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmF9kXM-pLs) and [also here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_T5Ng_QG9_A) are some video examples.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger movement means that the batsman is in ready position with either weight on the front foot and/or back foot. The trigger is repeatable ball after ball, so the batsman is in the right mental and physical space.